# MapReduce for finding a string using Java

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to search a particular string from a text file and occurance of that string but after running this code I am getting classCastException between io.LongWritable.

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
        at searchaString.SearchDriver$searchMap.map(SearchDriver.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

16/04/30 02:48:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/04/30 02:48:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1461630807194_0021_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

```
package samples.wordcount;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
//import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.NLineInputFormat;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        JobClient jobC =new JobClient();

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        //String args[] = parser.getRemainingArgs();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJobName("WordCount");


        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        //job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        /*String MyWord = args[2];
        TokenizerMapper.find = MyWord;*/

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ?  0:1);
    }

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        //  private Text word = new Text();
        static String find="txt was not created";
        public int i;

        public void map(Text key, Text value,OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,Reporter reporter) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String cleanLine = value.toString();        

            String[] cleanL =cleanLine.split("home");

            output.collect(new Text(cleanL[1]), one);

        }
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {



        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int sum = 0;

            String wordText="txt was not created";

            while(values.hasNext()) {

                Boolean check = values.toString().contains("txt was not created");

                if(check)
                {
                    String[] cleanL =values.toString().split("\\.");

                    for(String w : cleanL)
                    {
                        if(w.length()>=wordText.length())

                        {
                            String wrd = w.substring(0,wordText.length()); 

                            if(wrd.equals(wordText))
                            {
                                IntWritable value=values.next();
                                sum += value.get();

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            output.collect(key,new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to this MapReduce and Not sure how to do this.

also this is how my text file look:

tab/hdhd/hip/home.slkj.skjdh.dgsyququ/djkdjjd.****text was not created**
I have to search that particular text occurrences.

Kindly reply.

If you share some solution kindly explain in brief what should I change in code.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using TextInputFormat then the Tokenizer mapper should look like this:
 public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>

Comment: I tried with that too but it still gives the error

Comment: Is it possible for you to have a webex session or something similar where I can show you my code and you can suggest changes

Comment: @Sachin:When I am keeping LongWritable it says Expected Text but it's LongInt

Comment: Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable................ Now this is the error

Comment: Seems like you are mixing old api syntax with `map` & `reduce` methods' signature. As far I remember the new api doesn't use `OutputCollector` & `Reporter`. It should be something like `void map(Class1 key, Class2 value, Context context)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.............I changed it Context context............. But I am still getting same error.......................Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Comment: If you want we can have a webex @george

Answer (score 0):

You have given the signature of Mapper class as below

public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper

The input key taken by map method is the byteoffset of the lines. For example if below are the contents of ur file

Hello World!

The map fuction will take the byteoffset of first line(in Hexadecimal)as key  and "Hello World!" as value. ByteOffset is a kinf of Long value.

Change the input key to LongWritable

Comment: New Mapper:



public class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, 

Text, IntWritable> {


 private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);


 static String find="txt was not created";


 public int i;



public void map(LongWritable lb, Text value,Context cont) throws IOException, InterruptedException

 {


  String cleanLine = value.toString();     

  String[] cleanL =cleanLine.split("home");

  cont.write(new Text(cleanL[1]), one);

 }

}

Comment: not able to give enter in between lines in comments

Comment: Main Class
  public class WordCount {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
  job.setJobName("WordCount");
  job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
  job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
  job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);

Comment: MAIN CLASS PART 2: job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ?  0:1);
 }
}

Comment: I am not able to get the result even after changing it             Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Comment: @george if you want we can have a webex

Comment: @SachinJanani  Thanks a lot. Please send your details to me, at my email: georgekhatri@hotmail.com

Comment: New Mapper: public class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>

And ur write method is
cont.write(new Text(cleanL[1]), one); 

"one" is not of IntWritabe thing. Either change ur signature like below
public class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable

Answer (score 0):

New Mapper: public class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper

And ur write method is
cont.write(new Text(cleanL[1]), one);

"one" is not of IntWritabe thing. Either change ur signature like below
public class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper and write as below

cont.write(new Text(cleanL[1]), new Text("one"));

OR

public class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper and write as

cont.write(new Text(cleanL[1]), new IntWritable(1);